# Weak (Brouwerian) Counterexample for existence of right inverse of a surjection

Tags: constructive-mathematics

I'm dealing with Exercise 2 of *Bishop's Constructive Analysis*, Chapter 2 :

> 2. Construct a mapping $f$ from a set $A$ to a set $B$ such that $f$ is
>      onto $B$, but there does ***not*** exist a mapping $g: B \rightarrow
>     A$ with $f (g(b)) = b$ for all $b$ in $B$.

I don't know how to define $A$ in order to reach *weak* contradiction of ***choosing*** one member of the set $f^{-1}(b)$ for each $b$.

Such a set must be an undecidable set, like $\{x|(x=0\wedge p)\vee(x=1\wedge \neg p)\}$, where $p$ is NOT known to be true or not, like *Goldbach conjecture*. And existence of such a $g:B\rightarrow A$ must prove $p$ is true or not !

Another set $A$ can be, for example, $\mathbb{R}$ which doesn't have *trichotomy* or *equality decidability*.

Any help is appreciated.

---

#**EDIT** :

I think this map doesn't work, but it's not a bad try ($GC$ is *Goldbach conjecture*):

Let $A=\{x|(x=0\wedge GC)\vee(x=1\wedge \neg GC)\}$ and $B=\{2\}$. $A$ is *nonempty* but it's not *nonvoid* in the sense of *Bishop's Book*.

Define the function : $\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
f:A\rightarrow B\\
f(x)\equiv2\end{array}\right.$.

Now, if there exists such a $g:B\rightarrow A$, then $g(2)$ is available !!! (not useful ?!)

Comment: You're overthinking this. If there's a choice to be made for some $b$, then you can't satisfy all the preimages. Your construction (you get to choose the map!) should be very simple and not involve the axiom of choice. (Also, I think you get to choose $A$ and $B$ since this would be true if $A$ were the empty set or a one-point set.)

Comment: Indeed, the map $g$ must decide about some global property of $A$ which is undecidable !

Answer (score 1):

I think i've find the counterexample :

Let $A=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\{a,b\}$, where $(a=b \longleftrightarrow GC)$.
[I saw this idea in the proof of ($AC\rightarrow LEM$)]

Now define $\left\{
\begin{array}{}
f:A\rightarrow B\\
f(0)=a \:,\:f(1)=b
\end{array}\right.$

Clearly, $f$ is a surjection. If such a $g$ exists, then you can decide on *equality* of $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ as equality of members of $A$ is decidable !

Hence, 
$\left\{
\begin{array}{}
g(a)=g(b) \rightarrow a=b\\
g(a)\neq g(b)\rightarrow a\neq b
\end{array}\right.$. Therefore, you can decide on equality of $a$ and $b$ and so on *Goldbach's conjecture*

#Contradiction !